# HTML/JQuery Mobile Removing Up-And-Down Clickers on Number Input Fields

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have the following code for a mobile app that takes an input of numbers:

```
<label for="number"> How much is your bill?</label>
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" placeholder="Enter a Value" required="true" />
<input type="submit" value = "Submit">
<input type="reset" value = "Clear">
```

It should look something like this:

http://oi49.tinypic.com/33zg2zp.jpg

I was wondering if it's possible to remove the up-and-down toggles on the side of the number input field. Please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT: oops, I fixed the link. The picture should be working now.

Comment: You are missing the link, buddy (after, "it looks something like this").

Comment: Fixed the link, although it seems it's a bad URL.

Answer (score 0):

That's like asking to remove the down-arrow from a SELECT.

You can try to cover it up, but you can't change the native behaviour of that type of control.